# Angular ng-href in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in a template that is in a route in Angular:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-href="/create>Create</a>
```

I have this route defined:

```
.when("/create", {
        templateUrl: page_root + 'html/createhtml'
    })
```

The link links to `http://mysite/create` instead of `http://mysite/somepath#!/create`

Why is this?  On the main page (not in a `<ng-view>` section of the page I have:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-href="/">Home</a>
```

This creates the proper link `http://mysite/somepath`

Why does the template not know where the root of the site is?

Comment: The router is probably attempting to use pretty urls. Try to set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` in your router configuration.

Comment: On a side note, you could switch to using ui-router, which lets you use `ui-sref` instead of `ng-href` - that way you can reference your routes by name. Configuration is simple and switching from the build-in router is trivial (with only a few simples routes, you're done in <5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the *href* as '#create' instead of '/create'. You may also verify if the href property is appropriately generated by inspecting the anchor element.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-href="#create">Create</a>
```

Also I don't see any advantage of using `ng-href` for static Urls. You should simply use `href`.